# How could we understand or rephrase this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

When reading [a paper](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/31/11/4187/4708265), I saw a sentence

> Overall, these results suggest that firms do respond to increased
> competition **by making organizational and top management changes that
> improve efficiency**.

I am quite confused with the bold phrase. Does it mean that firms make organizational changes and top management change to respond to increased competition, and both organizational change and top management change help improve efficiency?

Comment: Actually it does. because of the phrase "***do respond***". but the second part of your question is not necessarily true, for changing in some aspects and things my not lead to improvement at all. but the author claims it and we say OK.

Comment: @AtrinNoori . I am wondering the last "that" stands for both "top management change" and "organizational change" or only "top management change"?

Comment: Well yeah it is a good idea to be stuck in, I believe that "that" is for both but we can still think on it. well for one if that is for "top management change" then you have to use "improves", but as we have "changes" as a plural word it can make it back to "improve" again. but there is this other idea of sharing the word "changes" between "organizational and top management" in that case we will be sure that "that" stands for both. if it is still confusing I can give it an answer with better choice of words

Comment: @AtrinNoori that's great, it is clear now to me. Thank you so much.

Comment: your welcome, Hope that helped